# Homestead - Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying

Tags: homestead

I had Homestead fully working. I have tried to play along with Docker, now Homestead is not running up.

Any ideas what to check?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to a temporary fault with a third party service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I needed to use homestead destroy. I am running up again.